# Invalid Directory Name

Tags: python, directory

I am receiving the error:

```
File "C:/Users/AM/PycharmProjects/booyah/first.py", line 5, in main
directory = os.chdir(input('Enter the directory of the file you want to read'))
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\AM\\Desktop\\Sad.txt'
```

Here is my code:

```
import os

def main():
    answer = input('Would you like to read, write, create, or quit?')
    if(answer == 'read'):
        directory = os.chdir(input('Enter the directory of the file you want to read'))
        w = open(directory, 'r')
        contents = w.read()
        print(contents)
        w.close()
```

The directory I copy into leads to a text file on my desktop.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code is throwing a 'NotADirectoryError' and your input ends in 'Sad.txt'... I dont think directories end in .txt?

Comment: A `directory` does not equate to a `path`. You are supplying the latter. If you want the directory of the file, call `os.path.dirname(file_variable)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous as to what you want to achieve here, but here's a quick example of how to parse the `read` command, `chdir` into the *directory* specified, and print out the lines of the file.

I have hardcoded the file name in this example:

```
import os

answer = input('Would you like to read, write, create, or quit?: ')
file_name = 'Sad.txt'

if(answer == 'read'):
    directory = os.chdir(input('Enter the directory of the file you want to read: '))

    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            print(line)
```

...and here's a very brief example showing reading the file if you want the user to send in the path that includes the file as well:

```
import os

answer = input('Would you like to read, write, create, or quit?: ')

if(answer == 'read'):
    file_name = input('Enter the file you want to read: ')

    with open(file_name, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            print(line)
```